# nginx subs_filter for GET request only?

Tags: nginx

I would like to modify the html as it comes from the webapp before delivering it to the website visitor. However, if the website visitors posts in a web formula the input is also transformed by nginx's `subs_filter`.

Is it possible to use nginx's `subs_filter` for `GET` request only but not for `POST`?

---

Similar question (non-duplicate!) [nginx `sub_filter` for `GET` request only?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1021425/nginx-sub-filter-for-get-request-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `subs_filter_bypass` directive. From the [docs](https://github.com/yaoweibin/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module):

> You can specify several variables with this directive. If at least one
> of the variable is not empty and is not equal to '0', this substitution
> filter will be disabled.

```
map $request_method $is_post {
    default 0;
    POST 1;
}

server {
    server_name example.com;
    subs_filter ...;
    subs_filter_bypass $is_post;
}
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1021425/nginx-sub-filter-for-get-request-only